# Why is my hadoop reducer not running / being called?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676505/hadoop-reducer-not-being-called), my reducer was not running.

Unfortunately, his solution of setting the MapOutput{key|Value} does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was to change my `reduce()` to receive `Iterable<MyWritable>` instead of `Iterator<MyWritable>`, as describe on [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/22595).